# Android: can a activity have two or more classes?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context

In my app I want to have a separate class where it inflates menu items, so that I can use it for all activities instead of writing the code again and again. Please explain how to do it?

Comment: [See the docs on how to create a Java class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html)

Answer (score 4):

Write an Activity class that only inflates the menu items then use Inheritance and have your activities extend your MenuActivity class.

This is kinda what you would do in the master class.

```
public class MenuActivity extends Activity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       //inflate menu
    }
}
```

Then make your main activity extend Menu Activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends MenuActivity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      //inflate other views
   }
}
```

when a call is made to super it tells the super class to execute that methods code.
More about class inheritance http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: Agreed. Create a common class that your other activities extend and override the method there, having multiple classes for a single Activity would be a very poor solution.